# String length is showing different when calling from a file in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, string-length

I am reading a string from two different methods.
String is ALLAMNOOSWTYVNMNN

1. Reading a string from a file and checking the length.
2. Reading string directly and checking the length function.

Output when reading from text file shows 18 instead of 17.

```
seqe= open("aaaa.txt", "r")
    if seqe.mode == 'r':
    seq =seqe.read()
print(len(seq))
```

String is `ALLAMNOOSWTYVNMNN`

it should print 17 when printing length.

I was expecting the length in both will be same but when printing it shows 17 and when reading from file same string is showing 18

Comment: use `print(len(seq.strip()))` -- You probably have an extra space or a new-line char

Comment: Thanks dear. It works..!!